# Resample Pandas Dataframe based on defined value

Tags: python, pandas

I'm trying to set the 'Num' column to a max/min threshold of 10 and reindex the dataframe based on this aggregation.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy

df = pd.DataFrame({'Num':[2,12,4,25,5]})

----------------------------------------

   Num
 0  2
 1  12
 2  4
 3  25
 4  5
```

How can I re-index the Pandas Dataframe so it looks like this?

```
   Num
0   10
1   10
2   10
3   10
4   8
```

Thanks!

Comment: I do not understand how you are obtaining your desired output. Can you explain in more detail?

Comment: I do not really understand how 2 and 4 are supposed to turn into 10 while 5 is turning into 8. Could you please clarify what you want to do?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Seems like you need

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Num':[2,12,4,25,5]})
s=df.Num.sum()
df.iloc[:s//10,0]=10
df.iloc[-1,0]=10 if s%10==0 else s%10

df
Out[369]: 
   Num
0   10
1   10
2   10
3   10
4    8
```

Comment: Thanks! Just what I was looking for.

Comment: @BillyRay yw :-) happy coding , and maybe include more detail for future question :-)

Comment: @Scotty1-  thank you man , just feel like this should be the one way for even the value cross the columns